# What are all the positions for geom_bar() and geom_col()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-col

I've looked in an infinity of places, but none of them actually put all the `position`s available for these two `geom`s. I know there are `stack` (to put one on top of the other), `dodge` (to make little clusters with each group side-by-side), `identity` (to leave them one in front of the other), and `fill` (to make them fill the `y`-axis, acting as a part of a whole). But are there any others?

I was wondering if there were a place were all the available `positions` are, or at least, if anyone knows of other options.

This is an example of `position`:

```
[...]
geom_bar(position = "stack")
[...]
```

or with `geom_col()` (works either way).

Comment: Please check this https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/

Comment: Oh, I thought `position` were exclusive for these two `geoms`... Thanks!

Answer (score -10, accepted):

If you want to get help to arguments of a function, just call the help

```
?geom_bar
```

There you will find

```
position:   
Position adjustment, either as a string, or the result of a call to a position adjustment function.
```

So, lets google something like "ggplot position adjustment function".
The first result is the ggplot2 reference https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/.
There you find "Position adjustment" and a list of linked position adjustments.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Half of this answer is explaining how to pull up documentation that gives a uselessly vague description. The other half is (condescension combined with) an external link.

Comment: I followed your instructions and ended up back on this page